# How to use environment variables in debian/install

Tags: debian, packaging

How can I use environment variables inside the "install" file in the debian directory.

I want to do something like this :

```
Resources      $HOME/somefolder
```

However this is creating a folder called $HOME in the deb package and lintian is giving me a warning :

*W: file-in-unusual-dir $HOME/somefolder*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debian packages install software system-wide.
Also, only superuser can install packages, no ordinary user.
A system typically has multiple users (my Desktop machine that has 2 user accounts for real world people, has a total of 38 different user accounts, most of them being system-users for specific programs (e.g. a webserver running as user `www-data`)

In this context `${HOME}` doesn't make sense (whose home directory? root? a special pseudouser for your application? all users?).

Therefore, you should re-think how you install your package:

- data that is valid for all users should go into `/usr/share/<myapp>` (for architecture independent data) or `/usr/lib/<myapp>` (for architecture dependent data).
- per-user data should not be installed by the package at all! If it's absolutely necessary to have user-data installed prior to running your application (e.g. because the application will refuse to run without having user-data installed somewhere in ${HOME}), you should still put that data in a central place (`/usr/share` or `/usr/lib`) and either create a setup-script that each user has to run before starting the application for the first time and which will copy (or symlink) the contents from the central location to the user's ${HOME}. Alternatively, you could do a wrapper, that will check whether the data is there (and eventually copy/symlink it) before running the real program.

You might want to have a look at the [FileSystemHierarchy](http://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard) and the [Debian Policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/).